# WPF Battery Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a WPF control that looks like an iPhone battery level.  I found a brush which will paint a battery similar to it.  But its just a static brush - I need to do a bunch of animating.

Anyone seen one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy seems to have created one that looks similar:
http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/iphones-beautiful-battery-recharger-as-a-silverlight-animation/

Source code: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1e3f9e1e2f8bc994&id=1E3F9E1E2F8BC994%21221#

Comment: Thanks that does help a bunch.  I just have to tweak it to turn it into a WPF control.