# Porting silverlight control to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use this for my WPF application. [WPF Battery Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390741/wpf-battery-control).
It is about a IPhone based battery control in silverlight.

However, I have no idea how to go about it, and would like to ask for help.

Here is the link: http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/iphones-beautiful-battery-recharger-as-a-silverlight-animation/

And source code: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1e3f9e1e2f8bc994&id=1E3F9E1E2F8BC994%21221#

Answer (score 0):

if you have the source, just make a WPF app, and add the code for the control. it should build w/o any problem.

silverlight is a sub-set of WPF, so most silverlight code should build w/o any problem. the reverse is not true, however--most WPF code won't build in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've linked to is a Silverlight 1 application, so porting isn't simply a case of copy the source across.

The XAML markup for the battery is in `iTunesControls\Recharging\BatteryRecharging.xaml`.  Most of this appears to work as-is.  Copy the entire contents of this file into a user control or custom control in your WPF project, and then remove the `xmlns`, `xmlns:x` and `xmlns:a` namespace references and the `x:Class` attribute from the root `<Canvas>` element.

To vary the amount of charge shown within the battery, set the `Width`s of the elements with names `pthFiller` and `pthFiller1` to a value between 0 (empty) and 314 (100% full).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. However, just another question. Value of pthFiller1 does not seem to affect the amount of charge.

Comment: @DavidGuetta: the element with name `pthFiller1` is part of the reflection.  Ideally you'd want to keep this having the same width as `pthFiller`, so that the reflection of the battery shows the same amount of charge as the battery itself.